# How pass value declared in application controller to component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my application controller, i have the following:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isOpen: true,

  actions: {
    toggleSidebar () {
      this.toggleProperty('isOpen');
    }
  }
});
```

And i would like to pass the isOpen to a component that is being called from other templates (not application.hbs), like:

```
{{#main-main isOpen=isOpen}}
{{/main-main}}
```

because inside the component i have:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'main',
    classNames: ['main'],
    classNameBindings: ['isOpen:main--active'],
});
```

I was thinking that should work just like this.. but it doesn't.

What could i do to pass the property isOpen to the component main-main?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every template (templates/example.hbs) where you want to pass `isOpen` property to component you have to declare `isOpen` property in controller associated with that template (controllers/example.js).

You can achieve this by using dependency injection in controllers/example.js:

```
application: Ember.inject.controller(),
isOpen: Ember.computed.alias('application.isOpen')
```

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: Daniel.. is possible to listen to isOpen? In this case i'm just passing the value, right?

Comment: It is possible to listen for isOpen, but you need to first call property application in your controller because it's lazily evaluated. Then you have to create observer instead of computed property alias. Now, you're passing `isOpen` value, but it's two-way binding so it updates automatically and you have always the most up-to-date value of `application` controller's `isOpen` property in other controllers if you use `comuted.alias`.

Comment: So, i should use like: isOpen: Ember.observer('application.isOpen', function..., right?

Comment: Yeah, but you also need to call `this.get('application.isOpen')` or this observer won't fire at all because it's lazily evaluated.

Comment: Hei @Daniel Kmak, i'm sorry for taking or time, but can you take a look -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbZrKK Am i doing wrong? Cause is not working